# TestFlight Upload w/ Same Version Number during Shutdown

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

As iTunes Connect will be [taking a break from Dec 22 to 29](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process#68611491) and it states that TestFlight submissions for external testing won't be available during this time. I'm wondering does that mean absolutely no upload of builds for TestFlight beta testing, or just those that need to be reviewed by Apple?

Say I upload a new build, with the same version number but different build number during the holiday break, would I be able to release it to external tester if I indicate that no significant changes are made and no review is needed for TestFlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking to Developer Support they clarified what is meant by the extract shared above.

> From December 22 to December 29, 2015, the following features will be unavailable:
>
> App submissions for new apps and app updates
>
> App bundle submissions for new bundles and bundles updates
>
> In-App Purchase submissions
>
> **TestFlight submissions for external testing**

No uploads what so ever of current or incremented build will be available during the 7 days starting Monday the 22nd of December until Monday the 29th of December 2015. Application Loader and Xcode upload will not be able to submit any binaries to iTunes Connect and you won't be able to submit any builds for review, both Test Flight and App Store.

Hope that helps, Julian

Comment: Yes this is the answer I'm looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to upload TestFlight builds for external testers sadly, quoting your reference:

> From December 22 to December 29, 2015, the following features will be unavailable:
>
> App submissions for new apps and app updates
>
> App bundle submissions for new bundles and bundles updates
>
> In-App Purchase submissions
>
> **TestFlight submissions for external testing**

Comment: Hmm... The way I understand "submissions" is submit for review, not submit to iTunes Connect...

Comment: I interpret "submit" as meaning upload... but you are right the language is not clear.